# Unable to resolve FaceBook Fan Page RSS June 2015

Tags: facebook, rss, facebook-page, broken-pipe, facebook-feed

I was pulling RSS feed from a few Fan Pages and posting to our sites. suddenly Facebook seems to have blocked or shut off RSS feeds. I am not finding a good solution or method to pull these posts from a few facebook pages ... Anyone have any suggestions?

A little more detail I was using IFTT.com to pull the rss feed and then put it were I wanted it. So the trigger was:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=(page id)
 Suddenly all of these return the following error 
Not a valid feed url, missing feed title

Any suggestions code gurus?

Answer (score 2):

The RSS feed is gone, the only way to get the Page feed is the feed endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed

You will need an App for this though, because you need to use a Token for the endpoint. An App Access Token is good enough though, so the API endpoint would look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page-id]/feed?access_token=APPID|APPSECRET
```

More information about Access Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/